# which rule can conduct this formula $\log n = O(n^{0.000001})$?

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

i am learning this [post](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/assignments/MIT6_006F11_ps1_sol.pdf) about Big O, which gives this formula

$$\log n = O(n^{0.000001})$$

why is that?

Comment: check the definition of Big-O, seems that you don't know it ;)

Comment: With mathematics, it's usually best not to think in terms of "rules". Instead, try to understand the concepts.

Comment: @Bulat Not necessarily. Even somebody who knows the definition might not know why $\log n = O(n^{0.000001})$.